# model a system with finite users as a Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I have to model a system M/M/2 with finite users (4 users) as a Markov Chain (and then find the probality an incoming users would enter the queue being the servers busy but that's not the problem).
I am a little confused if a system with finite users can be modelled this way. The M says that the arrival process is markovian but how it can be? For example the state of the system is taken in consideration (if there are already 4 users in the system the arrival rate is 0) so the property that a markovian process must be "without memory" is invalid. Moreover the fact that the arrival rate when there are 4 users capable of arriving is the same as when there are only 2 users available is counterintuitive. Could someone explain please? Thanks

Comment: Markovian means with no memory of what happened **before** the present, of course the next state depends on the current state.

Comment: Moreover, I see no reason to think the arrival rate would depend on the number of users. Think of a website, do you know how many users are currently on the website before you click to go on it?

Comment: Well when the number of users is infinite (or very high) I agree but when the users are a limited number It's difficult thinking that the arrival rate isn't related to how much users are already in the system

Comment: What do you mean by limited number of users? Is it that requests are not treated when 4 users are being served? Or something else?

Comment: There are only 4 users in the world

Comment: Might it be that you are mistaken and that the maximum number of users  in the system (including those in service) is 4? If it is really just 4 users, then just consider a few different scenarios. Note that only users 3 and 4 can potentially wait and think about the case that user 1 and 2 are still in the system, or that only user 1 is left, or only user 2 is left, etc.